# Python docs article "Security considerations" about SSL context with `smtplib`

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, smtplib

## 1. `smtplib.SMTP_SSL`

In the Python 3 Docs at [`smtplib.SMTP_SSL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) it says:

> `class smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='', port=0, local_hostname=None, keyfile=None, certfile=None, [timeout, ]context=None, source_address=None)`
>
> (...) *context,* also optional, can contain a [`SSLContext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) and allows configuring various aspects of the secure connection. Please read [Security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-security) for best practices.

---

## 2. Security considerations article

So read the above mentioned [Security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-security) where it says:

> (...) it is highly recommended that you use the `create_default_context()` function to create your SSL context.

and

> (...) if you create the SSL context by calling the `SSLContext` constructor yourself, it will not have certificate validation nor hostname checking enabled by default.

So it seems like I definitively want the former: `create_default_context` for the SSL context.

---

## 3. `smtplib.py`

I had a quick look at [`smtplib.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/smtplib.py#L994) to see what happens, if I omit the `context` argument of `smtplib.SMTP_SSL`:

> `if context is None:
>       context = ssl._create_stdlib_context(certfile=certfile,
>                                             keyfile=keyfile)`

So there is a call to `ssl._create_stdlib_context` which seems different from the recommended `ssl.create_default_context` from the Security considerations article.

---

## 4. `ssl.py`

At the function docstring in [`ssl.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ssl.py) I found:

> `All Python stdlib modules shall use this function to create SSLContext
>   objects in order to keep common settings in one place. The configuration
>   is less restrict than create_default_context()'s to increase backward
>   compatibility.`

---

## 5. Question

How am I supposed to call `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` according to the Security considerations article? It seems like I really need to "manually" call `create_default_context` to create a context each time?

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(context=ssl.create_default_context())
```

Or is

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL()
```

enough? And why?

Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is using `server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(context=ssl.create_default_context())`.

Acoording to docstring, `_create_stdlib_context` is less restrict than `create_default_context` because of backward compatibility.

ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ssl.py#L581

Comment: From [the code in 3.7.1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/ssl.py#L628): `_create_stdlib_context = _create_unverified_context`. So yes, definitely less secure since the default context is doing certificate validation while `_create_stdlib_context` obviously not.

Comment: @Jayjayyy: it looks sufficient to just use the default context. This enables proper certificate validation including validation of the target hostname against the certificates subject/SAN.